# Is this combinatorial equality correct?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to prove this equality, where $P_k$ only depends on $k$.

$$p_m - \sum_{k=m+1}^n\binom{k}{m} \sum_{h=k}^{n} (-1)^{h-k}\binom{h}{k}p_{h} = \sum_{k=m}^{n} (-1)^{k-m}\binom{k}{m}p_{k}$$

But I am really stuck!
My attempts involve trying to switch the summation, trying to prove that $$p_m - \sum_{k=m+1}^n\binom{k}{m} \sum_{h=k}^{n} (-1)^{h-k}\binom{h}{k}p_{h} = \sum_{k=m}^n\binom{k}{m} \sum_{h=k}^{n} (-1)^{h-k}\binom{h}{k}p_{h}$$, but I have not been able to get any headways.

I think an identity regarding $\sum_{h=k}^{n} (-1)^{h-k}\binom{h}{k}p_{h}$ would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=m+1}^n\binom{k}m\sum_{h=k}^n(-1)^{h-k}\binom{h}kp_h+\sum_{k=m}^n(-1)^{k-m}\binom{k}mp_k\\
&\qquad=\sum_{k=m}^n\binom{k}m\sum_{h=k}^n(-1)^{h-k}\binom{h}kp_h\\
&\qquad=\sum_{m\le k\le h\le n}(-1)^{h-k}\binom{h}k\binom{k}mp_h\\
&\qquad=\sum_{h=m}^np_h\sum_{k=m}^h(-1)^{h-k}\binom{h}k\binom{k}m\\
&\qquad=\sum_{h=m}^np_h\binom{h}m\sum_{k=m}^h(-1)^{h-k}\binom{h-m}{k-m}\\
&\qquad=\sum_{h=m}^np_h\binom{h}m\sum_{k=0}^{h-m}(-1)^{h-m-k}\binom{h-m}k\\
&\qquad=\sum_{h=m}^np_h\binom{h}m\sum_{k=0}^{h-m}(-1)^{h-m-k}\binom{h-m}{h-m-k}\\
&\qquad=\sum_{h=m}^np_h\binom{h}m\sum_{k=0}^{h-m}(-1)^k\binom{h-m}k\\
&\qquad=\sum_{h=m}^np_h\binom{h}m(1-1)^{h-m}\\
&\qquad=p_m\,,
\end{align*}$$

since $0^0=1$ and $0^\ell=0$ for $\ell\ge 1$.